# Google contacts API with javascript client

Tags: javascript, google-contacts-api, google-api-js-client

I'd like to retrieve a list of a users contacts using the [google contacts api](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/contacts/v3/#running_the_sample_code). I've set up the authentication flow using the [javascript api library](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/javascript/start/start-js). I'm now trying to retrieve a list of contacts using the method

```
gapi.client.request({'path': 'https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/default/full'})
```

From the guide it seems pretty straight forward that you pass in the path into the request object. And it appears that this is the correct path `https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/default/full`. However I'm receiving a 404 not found error from google so something is off.

How can I retrieve a list of contacts from an authenticated user using the gapi javscript client?

Comment: Are you sure receiving a **404** ? No 401 or 403 ?

Comment: the Javascript client library implementation is wrong. If you try that using the [OAuth playground](https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/), you'll successfully be able to retrieve the list. Tried the Javascript client and it wasn't working for me as well as there's no specific contacts api sample. Try [this guide](https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/) .